# Get generic array class

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a function:

```
add(Collection<?> many)
```

I call it like this:

```
Collection<NewClass> awa = new ArrayList<NewClass>();
add(awa)
```

How do I get the `<?>` type? in that function?

`many.getClass()` gives `ArrayList`.

Why I need this? Trying to make a generic DAO method for adding a Collection of `< ? >`.

**EDIT:**

tried like this:

```
public static void add(Collection<?> many)  {
    Type typeArg = ((ParameterizedType)Testing.class.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    System.out.println(typeArg);
}

    Collection<NewClass> awa = new ArrayList<NewClass>();


    add(awa);
```

got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

Comment: [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is going to make that hard.

Comment: Why do you need to know the type?

Comment: @Code-Guru : Hibernate adds element to database by classname

Comment: @Jaanus Hibernate reads type parameters via reflection API from field or properties declarations.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda what do you mean?

Comment: See my answer below. Type erasure removes type arguments from object types but declarations of fields, methods, constructors etc. are left. You need to redesign the code to know the code on compile time.

Comment: How do you instantinate DAO in 'edit' example. It seems that you did not inherited it adn declared concreate class.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda look I put up the instantiation.

Comment: Show full `Testing` clas code. It needs to have a generic supertype. You need to extend a generic class defining generic type argument. Please see my answer - second example. There are classes like `class IntegerDAO extends GenericDAO<Integer> {}`. Type must be defined on compile time.

Answer (score 4):

`many.getClass()` gives `ArrayList`.

Sure, that sounds right.

What if you do `many.get(0).getClass()` instead? Here we're interrogating the element, and not the container, if that makes sense. I'm a C#er, so this may not be 100% the right way to do this, but it's the route I would take in C#.

Comment: This way you get the type of the first element. If the elements in the list don't have the same type this could easily be the most specific type. You would need to iterate over all elements and get the most generic type.

Comment: I assumed they would have the same type across all elements, and that he would use a guard clause, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could go around this issue and make your method generic, eg:

```
public <T> void add(Collection<T> blah){}
```

you can call it then by

```
this.<NewClass>add(awa);
```

if it's in a different class then

```
DifferentClass dc = new DifferentClass();
dc.<NewClass>add(awa);
```

Comment: To be correct, the method and Call are in different Class. Will it work?

Comment: sure, just use the class name/instance name instead of "this". (see edit)

Comment: Ok but how I get the class? This sends the class, but how I get it?

Comment: You would use T for the type inside of your method. If you mean you need to do conditionals based on what type of collection is passed in, then you would need to have a second parameter that somehow tells you the type. There is no non-overkill way (see Piotr's answer) for getting the type of a generic that I know of.

Comment: There is no reason to do this. It adds nothing to what he's already doing with `?`

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this :

```
public class Test {

  Test() {
    Collection<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    add(ints, Integer.class);
    Collection<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    add(strings, String.class);
  }

  public final <T> void add(Collection<T> many, Class<T> type) {
    System.out.println(type.getName());
    // do whatever needed.
  }

}
```

Comment: There was just a small mistake. It is the right idea, due to type erasure you need to provide the type at runtime explicitely.

Comment: This seems incredible overkill, as you're passing in a reference to the type which you can infer from the element, no? Every element carries a type, indeed this is the point of Java. So if you have an element (the function got called) then you have a type. There's no need to carry this extra baggage.

Comment: You can't infer the generic collection type from the element type. If each and every element is `java.lang.String` the collection type could still be `java.lang.Object`. There is no hint whatsoever.

Comment: The collection will always be just a collection. Collections are not interesting.

Comment: The generic collection parameter type, of course... that is what is needed for further processing (persisting or whatever).

Comment: What is needed for further processing? The type of the element inside the collection? So what I said?

Comment: You can't infer the type from the elements because they can be arbitrarily deep subclasses or implement interfaces that all could be the element type. E.g. a `List` containing `JButton`s could be any of `List<Object>`, `List<Component>`, `List<Container>`, `List<JComponent>`, `List<AbstractButtn>`, `List<JButton>`, `List<ImageObserver>`, `List<ItemSelectable>`, `List<MenuContainer>`, `List<Serializable>`, `List<Accessible>`, `List<SwingConstants>`. Without telling explicitely you just don't know. Declaring it as "not interesting" does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check actual type arguments on runtime but you can read this only via reflection API from field, method, constructor etc. Sample below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;


public class TypesSample {

    public List<String> sampleList;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field f = TypesSample.class.getField("sampleList");
        ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType)f.getGenericType();
        Type typeArgument = paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(paramType.toString() + " with argument : " + typeArgument.toString());
    }


}
```

it says : `java.util.List<java.lang.String> with argument : class java.lang.String`

You won't get actual parameter type from object reference because of type erasure.

//edit:

This is what you can do for your situation:

```
abstract class GenericDAO<T> {

    public void add(Collection<T> many) {
        Type typeArg = ((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println("This is a DAO for " + typeArg);
    }

}

    // create DAOs that define what type parameter is   
class IntegerDAO extends GenericDAO<Integer> {}
class StringDAO extends GenericDAO<String> {}
```

and then :

```
GenericDAO<Integer> integerDAO = new IntegerDAO();
integerDAO.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
GenericDAO<String> stringDAO = new StringDAO();
stringDAO.add(Arrays.asList("A","B","C"));
```

says:
    This is a DAO for class java.lang.Integer
    This is a DAO for class java.lang.String

But you need to explicitly declare what `T` is by extending generic class.

Comment: How to do this with a method parameter `Collection<?> param`?

Comment: doesn't really answer the question. answers a different question

Comment: @newacct actually second example is the only way to implement generic DAO and infer generic parameter. First example just defines the problem.

Comment: It still is only a workaround for the original question. But as the original question has to be answered with "impossible", good workarounds are all you can get.

Comment: Got error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` Look first post

Comment: You must define a subclass of GenericDAO that defines what `T` is. Actually GenericDAO should be abstract (fixed above).

Comment: I get the whole path, but I need the name of class, after the `.`. How I get only class name?

Comment: How would I know to use integerDAO, when I don't know which is the type from user.

Comment: I guess somwhere in frontend you should know what you want to save. How do you want to save an object to databse if you don't know the type? Your use case is very strange.

Comment: Well on my frontend, there is a function: `genericDao.save(Collection<?> anything)`, so he can send any collection with `save()` and always be able to do it.

Comment: Your design is very strange. You've mixed layers. You'll end up with a monster dao that will try to do everything based on arguments passed. Your businnes-layer public interface should mimic use-cases (in simple example) like : "addToCart", "addComment", "saveGame", "sendInvitation". And in business layer just use session/entityManager. Forget DAO-s, it's 19th century invention. It seems that you've put everyting in view layer and whatever is constructed in view layer you want to save to DB - it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Well when I look hibernate examples, they all use DAOs, can you give me example where they are more based on "sessions/entityManager" you talk about.